# How can $_POST pass input variables to MySQL query as integers, not 1?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, post

I have a table of numbers where the user should be able to edit the values and have the database updated on submit.

So far, my faulty code is updating every field with the value 1 on submit, regardless of what has been inputted.

**Code on submit:**

```
    //If the confirm button has been hit:
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Create the foreach loop
foreach($_POST['classtoupdate'] as $classes){

  //Grab the POST data and turn it into integers
    $class_id = (int)$classes; 
    $totalspcs = (int)$_POST['allspaces']; 
    $totalbkgs = (int)$_POST['allbookings']; 
    $newbies = (int)$_POST['noobs'];

//Change the booking numbers:
  $newdeets = "UPDATE classes SET total_spaces = '$totalspcs', total_bookings = '$totalbkgs', free_spaces = ('$totalspcs' - '$totalbkgs'), newbies = '$newbies' WHERE class_id = '$class_id')";
  echo $newdeets;
  mysqli_query($dbc, $newdeets);
}
  mysqli_close($dbc);
  echo 'All good, yay! <a href="admin.php">Go look</a>';

}
```

**Form:**

```
//create the form
echo '<form method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" >';

      echo '<tr><td>' . $class . '</td>';
      echo'<td>' . $new_date . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $new_time . '</td>';
      echo '<td><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input-mini" name="noobs[]" id="noobs[]" value="' . $newbies . '">';
      echo '<td><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input-mini" name="allspaces[]" id="allspaces[]" value="' . $totalspaces . '">';
      echo '<td><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input-mini" name="allbookings[]" id="allbookings[]" value="' . $bookings . '"
>';
      echo '<td>' . $freespaces . '</td>';
      echo' <input type="hidden" name="classtoupdate[]" id="classtoupdate[]" value="' . $class . '" />';
    }
    echo'</table>';
    // Make booking button
      echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right" value="Update">';
      echo '</form>';
```

**The echoed query results after inputting random values (not 1) in the form:**

```
UPDATE classes SET total_spaces = '1', total_bookings = '1', free_spaces = ('1' - '1'), newbies = '1' WHERE class_id = '26')
UPDATE classes SET total_spaces = '1', total_bookings = '1', free_spaces = ('1' - '1'), newbies = '1' WHERE class_id = '16')
```

..and so on for each table row. I can't find the problem replicated after extensive searching on SO and in the manuals.

I've tried intval(), serialize and array_map on the POST results (probably incorrectly); I've tried different foreach loops to translate them into integers, still no joy.

Any advice?

Comment: In your form, you are using `name="noobs[]"`. remove the `[]` and try again(for all fields).

Comment: sorry, I didnt see that you try to handle the array at the first time, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach($_POST['classtoupdate'] as $index => $classes){
```

and

```
$totalspcs = (int)$_POST['allspaces'][$index]; 
$totalbkgs = (int)$_POST['allbookings'][$index]; 
$newbies = (int)$_POST['noobs'][$index];
```

note the `$index` in each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
//Create the foreach loop
foreach($_POST['classtoupdate'][$i] as $classes){

  //Grab the POST data and turn it into integers
    $class_id = (int)$classes; 
    $totalspcs = (int)$_POST['allspaces'][$i]; 
    $totalbkgs = (int)$_POST['allbookings'][$i]; 
    $newbies = (int)$_POST['noobs'][$i];

//Change the booking numbers:
  $newdeets = "UPDATE classes SET total_spaces = '$totalspcs', total_bookings = '$totalbkgs', free_spaces = ('$totalspcs' - '$totalbkgs'), newbies = '$newbies' WHERE class_id = '$class_id')";
  echo $newdeets;
  mysqli_query($dbc, $newdeets);
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Looks good - I used Hereblur's similar answer simply for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

your POST variables are arrays (e.g. allspaces[])

so, this assignment is always giving you 1 as a result, because you're trying to cast an array to integer.

```
$totalspcs = (int)$_POST['allspaces'];
```

you should cycle your array and use the data in a different way.
If you don't need an array, get rid of the square brackets in the input name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you have named your input fields. `<input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input-mini" name="noobs[]">` The `[]` means that the data will be posted back to the server as an array, and you are type casting an array into an integer, which is why everywhere you are getting 1 as value. Lose the `[]`, eg. `<input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input-mini" name="noobs">` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example you should be able to use to solve your problem.

```
<?php
$foo = array('1','2','3');
$bar = array('4','5','6');

// Simulates the $_POST variable
$baz = array('foo'=>$foo, 'bar'=>$bar);

// You should ensure that all entries have an equal length before iterating through!
if(count($baz['foo']) === count($baz['bar'])){
    foreach($baz['foo'] as $key=>$value){
        $x = (int)$value;
        $y = (int)$bar[$key];
        var_dump($x, $y);
    }
}       
?>
```

The problem that you're having is that, even though you're looping through `$_POST['classtoupdate']`, you are still using `$_POST['allbookings']` and other fields which are still arrays.

Converting an array to an integer value will always return 1 if the array is not empty. So you'll have to extract the values from them.